# How to debug an Qt-Android application build with cmake?

Tags: android, qt, gdb, gdbserver

I want to debug a Qt based Android application which is build using cmake (instead of qmake).

The `androiddeployqt` command bundles the apk and adds `gdbserver`.  Then I can launch the gdb server via:

```
adb shell run-as com.package.name /data/data/com.package.name/lib/libgdbserver.so --once :5055 --attach $PID
```

and also I forward the port to my desktop via `adb forward tcp:5055 tcp:5055`

Attaching `gdb` from `Qt-Creator` succeeds but something seems to be missing.
I am not shown any symbols and the number of displayed threads is not coherent.

Comment: Have you tried a basic qmake project to see if the missing information is available there?

Comment: To be honest: No I have not. I trusted in blogs which tell that it works. However I finally got it working (see my Answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it running. For future documentation, here is what I was missing:
I needed the libraries of my application as well as the Qt libraries build in debug mode. Further more I needed the executables and libraries from the phone. I fetched them via

```
adb pull /system/bin  ./
adb pull /system/lib  ./
```

adb creates subfolders when pulling and that was one of my problems: All these files need to be stored in one single folder – so I moved them.

Finally I needed to make gdb use the collected files via

```
set auto-solib-add on
set solib-search-path /tmp/adb
```